# Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Button_Pressed : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        private int times = 5;
        public Text timesText;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timesText.text = "Button pressed " + times + " times";

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            times++;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently following a UI tutorial on YouTube. In the video the creator types the code exactly like above. And his compiles with no errors. However, when I do this, I get the following error:

`Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.`

Has C# changed? And what does `Top-Level` mean?

Comment: C# is updated from time to time, here's what's new with C# 11: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11

Comment: Here's a link about Top-Level statments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements

Comment: Here's some additional material for you to help avoid this type of error in the future: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

Please do not change your question (silently) adapting to already given answers. People reading this after the fact will have a hard time following what goes on, and formerly valid answers look wrong.

Having that said, your current issue is this:

```
void Start()
{
    private int times = 5;
    public Text timesText;
}
```

You cannot declare access modifiers for local variables (as that would make little sense, since they are scoped to the method anyway).

It looks like these should have been members of the type, and those two lines should go outside any method and inside the class declaration itself. Why you then have an empty Start-method is beyond me and hard to tell. From your question alone.

For completeness sake something like this **maybe**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class Button_Pressed : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private int times = 5; // Can't tell if you need this here as well...
        public Text timesText;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            times = 5;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            timesText.text = "Button pressed " + times + " times";

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                times++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Again, if that makes logically sense depends on what exactly you think it should do. And you haven't explained that in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket so the compiler is being thrown off.

You need to change:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            times++;
```

To:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
            times++;
}
```

You should also probably add a [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) to your project, and move the `times` and `timesText` declarations out of the `Start` method, like so:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class Button_Pressed : MonoBehaviour
    {

        private int times = 5;
        public Text timesText;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            timesText.text = "Button pressed " + times + " times";

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                times++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed and still get `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`

Comment: So it's a new error now? It looks like it wants you to define a namespace.

Comment: I've added some information about namespaces in my answer as well